# Getting started with GP GPU?

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu, amd-processor

I have two basic questions about getting started with GPGPU programming:

(1) If I do GPGPU on my Mac, will it affect the image on the monitor? How do I know the windowing system or other programs output is not competing for the GPU?

(2) Is there a way to try out AMD GPU programming somewhere without buying a high-end graphics card? The rental cloud places I have seen all use Nvidia. My computation would be logical integer (bit-twiddling) compute-bound, and I have read that AMD GPU is better for these applications.

Answer (score 1):

1) It won't affect the image on the monitor. And to check if another process is using the GPU you'll need something like AMD System Monitor for mac (this application only works on Windows)

2) Any radeon HD 4xxx and above supports OpenCL (previous card might support this, but I'm not sure). This mean **any** new AMD card you can buy, including the cheapest ones support OpenCL.

The difference between the expensive cards and the cheap ones is the number of stream processors. For example

- Radeon HD 4350: 80 stream processors
- Radeon x290:  2560 stream processors

Comment: GPGPU and graphics (e.g., OpenGL, DirectX, and desktop windows) _do_ "compete" for the GPU in that they are all using it and if one of them hogs it the others will get less of it. However, the driver manages access so you don't have to manually manage it. If you run slow kernels taking more than dozens of milliseconds you can reduce the smooth desktop experience. If your kernels take more than a few seconds the OS will terminate them. So design your GPGPU work to break up the job into lots of short pieces. You can do a lot of work in a few milliseconds on a GPU!

Comment: I have in mind long computations, hours, over gigabytes of data. (Some of the newer GPUs have multiple gigabytes on-card. It would be useful just to have a server with an AMD to rent, assuming they really are better at integer code than Nvidia).